# How do I install librdkafka on windows?

Tags: php, librdkafka

I followed the following steps:

1. Copy librdkafka.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 if x86 otherwise copy to C:\Windows\System32. Don't copy to both folders.
2. Then run regsvr32 librdkafka.dll in command prompt.
3. Then copy php_rdkafka.dll to ext folder of your PHP.
4. Then add `extension=php_rdkafka.dll` to your php.ini file
5. Restart PHP, DONE!!!

But when I run regsvr32 librdkafka.dll there are error that windows cannot register `.dll`. How can I install librdkafka on windows?

Comment: Can you provide the error you're recieving

Comment: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_rdkafka.dll' (tried: ext\php_rdkafka.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.), ext\php_php_rdkafka.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0.

Comment: Also when I run command regsvr32 librdkafka.dll. 
Unfortunately, it tells that the lib was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer was not found.

Comment: Can you try placing librdkafka.dll in the /PHP folder instead of in de /ext folder

Comment: Yes , I tried also to put into php folder.

Comment: An you're using the correct php version for the extension?

Comment: Yes, of course. My php version is 7.3 . I want to install first librdkafka.dll and then php-rdkafka in order to work with apache kafka in my project.

Comment: @СанжарАнарбай have you got any solution or any alternative? If yes, then please post your solution here because I am getting the exact same issue. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I have found solution! In Windows you need to download php_rdkafka.dll and put into folder where you have libraries of PHP and edit you php.ini file add extension=php_rdkafka.dll to your php.ini file and restart your Server! If your OS is Linux, it is not difficult to install Kafka library , first of all you need to install lirdkafka for Linux, then sudo pecl install rdkafka-3.0.3 , then edit php.ini file extension=rdkafka.so, and then install this library composer require enqueue/rdkafka , documentation https://php-enqueue.github.io/transport/kafka/#installation